# Refresh only the table content in a Template with new items (Django)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-templates

I am implementing a table with filters.
None of the existing libraries (such as DataTables) work for me because they are based on client pagination and I cannot bring all the data from my DB and paginate it in the client side since it has more than 5 million items.

So, the thing is that I want to be able to write something in an input field and filter the items in the table accordingly.
The URL where it all starts is:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/view-containing-the-table/

This url has the html cointained in **custom_table.html** (see the file below), which includes a sub-template called **table_rows.html**, which is **the one I want to refresh**

To do it I have done the following:

**Structure of my project:**

```
project
|-app
  |-static
  |  |-javascript
  |    |-myJS.js
  |
  |-templates
  |  |-templates1
  |    |-custom_table.html
  |    |-table_rows.html
  |
  |-views
  |  |-__init__.py   #Gathers all the views from othe files)
  |  |-ajaxCalls.py
  |  |-modelViews.py
  |
  |-urls.py
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^table_rows/$', views.tableRows, name='tableRows'),
```

**custom_table.html**

```
#extend and loads here

{% block content %}
<table id="myTable"">
    ...
    <thead> #headers and filters for each column </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
        {% include "templates1/table_rows.html" %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

inside the  of the table table, there is an input in every column. I can write in them and then press enter to trigger a function that will call the following ajax function:

**myJS.js**

```
function getFilteredData(){

    modelName = #get ModelName
    var filters = #get Filters

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url : "../get_filtered_data/",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            modelName: modelName,
            filters: JSON.stringify(filters)
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(json) {
            $("#table_body").html('').load("app/views/tableRows.html", {reg_list: json.result});
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            alert('Something went wrong');
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**ajaxCalls.py**

```
def get_filtered_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:

            [...]
            reg_list = query response with filtered Data from DB
            [...]

            return JsonResponse({"status": "ok", "result":reg_list})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "none"})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "none"})
```

**modelViews.py**

```
def tableRows(request):
    print("I'm in")

    return render(request, 'templates1/table_rows.html', {

})
```

Everything works fine until the point when I have to **load the reg_list inside the table**.
The following error appears in the Chrome Console:

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/view-containing-the-table/app/views/tableRows.html 404 (NOT FOUND)

So, aparently, the url is all messed up, since django is writing the new view in addition to the one already existing. Maybe there's something wrong with the routing?
I don't know how to proceed, help please.

Comment: DataTables.net has a serverSide option where paging and filtering is all done at the server. take a look at https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide then https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: I already tried, but I could not manage to make it work. However, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 Not Found is because the

```
$("#table_body").html('').load(
    "app/views/tableRows.html",
    {reg_list: json.result}
);
```

needs to be accessible as a static asset, not a view template. Copy/move `tableRows.html` to `app/static/` and update your `myJS.js` to the correct static url.

Or define a view in `urls.py` that matches `app/views/tableRows.html`. It looks as though only part of the `urls.py` was shared so I'm missing part of the picture.